# A conversão da cadeia de caracteres " no tipo 'integer' não é valida

Tags: vb.net

Estou criando um programa simples que registra o total de vendas e o valor já ganho com as vendas, porem, apos o usuario botar o valor da venda o programa da erro.

O erro é o seguinte:

> A conversão da cadeia de caracteres " no tipo 'integer' não é valida

Antes estava funcionando certo, porem só tinha 1 IF, agora tenho no total 10 IF, que registram de acordo com o numero de vendas o valor em variaveis diferente, o codigo em questão:

```
Public Class addvenda
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles boxvenda.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 0 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda1 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 1 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda2 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 2 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda3 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 3 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda4 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 4 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda5 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 5 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda6 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 6 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda7 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 7 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda8 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 8 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda9 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If
    If My.Settings.numerovendas = 9 Then
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.venda10 = boxvenda.Text
        My.Settings.totalvendas += boxvenda.Text
        Me.Close()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro deverá estar a acontecer porque o texto que está em `boxvenda.Text` está vazio e não pode ser convertido para um número válido.

Penso que desta forma consegue evitar o erro, e ao mesmo tempo otimizar bastante o seu código:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dblBoxVenda As Double = 0

    If My.Settings.numerovendas >= 0 And My.Settings.numerovendas <= 9 Then
        'Converter o valor da TextBox para Double, caso seja possível
        'Se não for possível, o valor é "0"
        Double.TryParse(boxvenda.Text, dblBoxVenda)

        'Pegar no setting correspondente
        My.Settings.Item(String.Format("venda{0}", My.Settings.numerovendas + 1)) = dblBoxVenda
        My.Settings.vendas += 1
        My.Settings.numerovendas += 1
        My.Settings.totalvendas += dblBoxVenda
        My.Settings.Save()

        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Convém não esquecer de evocar o `My.Settings.Save()`, caso contrário as alterações não serão gravadas no *click* do botão.